# RewriteRule not working on root url (http://domain.com) but works for urls with path (http://domain.com/foo)

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I have this piece of code in my htaccess:

```
First condition
------------------------------------------
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} GET
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/html/%{HTTP_HOST}/index.html -f
RewriteRule ^$ /cache/html/%{HTTP_HOST}/index.html [NC,L]

Second condition
------------------------------------------
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} GET
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/html/%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/index.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /cache/html/%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/index.html [L]
```

It should display cached html file for the current route if exists. I initialy had only the second condition and it was working as expected under my localhost (apache on windows).

Problem started when I moved it to the linux staging server - It just doesn't work on the root url.

I then tried to add the first condition (^$) but still no luck. So I tried to add (just for testing) this condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} GET
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/html/%{HTTP_HOST}/index.html -f
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ /cache/html/%{HTTP_HOST}/index.html [L]
```

And if I was routing to http://domain.com/index.html It did work and showed me the cached html.
I just can't figure it out

This is the full .htaccess file: http://pastie.org/private/esmto6wdcmwjhzuwfbi4xa (I am using Laravel if it matters)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can allays add RewriteLog, or if you have Apache 2.4 the LogLevel to see the actual error and trace

LogLevel alert rewrite:trace3

In this case you will see exactly what was compared to what. More info here http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging

In your case I think you are missing a RewriteBase:

RewriteBase /

On any case, add some Trace data to be sure.

Comment: The rewritebase didn't help :(. I'll try to trace it and see what I get. thank dude

Comment: Add the trace for me to help you.